# Negative doubles or floats in Haskell (macports)

Tags: haskell, macports, ghci

Why do I get a segmentation fault when I try to show a negative double or float? There is no problem for negative integers.

```
Prelude> let a = 4
Prelude> :t a
a :: Integer
Prelude> let b = -4
Prelude> b
-4
Prelude> :t b
b :: Integer
Prelude> let c = 5.6
Prelude> :t c
c :: Double
Prelude> let d = -5.6
Prelude> :t d
d :: Double
Prelude> show d
"-Segmentation fault
```

I tried it various ways, it seems that the number is correctly understood but not shown. Version info:

```
ghci --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 6.10.4
```

Comment: Not reproducible on 6.10.4 either. Also when I run the code, `:t` shows the general, not the defaulted types (i.e. I get `Num t => t` and `Fractional t => t` as the types).

Comment: Would you happen to be using MacPorts? https://trac.macports.org/ticket/25265

Comment: Thanks KennyTM and Andrey. I guess you are right. I tried it on an older machine with ghc 6.8.2, and it works fine. But I am on the latest version of ghc on macport, so it seems its just a buggy version. Let me see if I can update it.

Comment: @Wesley, yes! macports've got to update it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GHC on MacPorts seems to be broken. See https://trac.macports.org/ticket/25265

Consider instead installing the Haskell Platform from haskell.org, which includes GHC 6.12.3 and a bundle of Haskelly goodies.

- Info: http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/
- Link: http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/mac.html

Comment: Yes, and macports is *really* broken. I tried installing haskell-platform macports remotely. It failed, spat out a log report, and I can't reach my remote machine anymore.

Comment: I'm afraid I wasn't very clear; I meant that you might want to install the binary provided at the link above rather than install the one through MacPorts. I would assume that the MacPorts haskell-platform would just include GHC 6.10.4 again.

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing you should realise is that segmentation faults should *never* occur in Haskell. Its type system ensures that nothing like that "goes wrong" at runtime.  If you do see a segmentation fault then either there is a bug in your Haskell compiler or you're interfacing to C code with the Haskell FFI and something has gone wrong with your C code.  In pure Haskell code, however, you should never see this.

Answer (score 1):

*March 2011*: This is fixed in the GHC 7 release of the [Haskell Platform](http://haskell.org/platform), where both 32 bit and 64 bit Mac native ports are in fine condition.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me on 6.12.3.  Could be a bug in that version.