# haskell negative decimal numbers

Tags: macos, haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Negative doubles or floats in Haskell (macports)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101599/negative-doubles-or-floats-in-haskell-macports)

I am new to haskell, and when I try to enter negative floating point numbers (e.g. -1.0) into ghci or use them in modules, I keep getting segmentation faults.

How do I give negative floating point values to variables w/o causing seg faults?

My apologies ahead of time if this is a total noob question, but I am kind of shocked this is as hard as it is...

Comment: Everything works fine here. GHCi 6.10.3 running on Windows 7. I think this is probably a bug, and if it is, you should report it to the authors of GHC instead.

Comment: Hmm that's not right.  Could you give some information about what compiler (GHC maybe?) you are using, what operating system, and give a concrete example with console output?

Comment: Is it actually a system SEGFAULT? That shouldn't happen, at all

Comment: As surprised as I am I can actually reproduce this using GHCi 6.10.4 on OS X. (Seems to be the *printing* of negative floats that causes a segfault)

Comment: See possibly [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101599/negative-doubles-or-floats-in-haskell-macports) and [this ticket](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/25265).

Comment: The macports ticket is exactly the behavior I was seeing and I am in fact running macports.  Looks like I will be re-installing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a broken MacPorts build of GHC. Please try the [Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/mac.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that this is a bug in ghci. You may consider changing the version of ghci or use hugs instead till the problem is fixed. If you get a segfault, something is going terribly wrong, as the RTS will normally ensure that this won't happen.