# ghci segfault with simple math

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

Can anyone explain this to me? I'm using a recent version of the GHC.

```
Prelude> let f x = 1/((x**2)-36)  
Prelude> f (0 - 6.5)  
0.16  
Prelude> f (0 - 5.999)  
-Segmentation fault  
Prelude> f (0 - 5)  
-Segmentation fault
```

Thanks!

Edit: GHCi version 6.10.4, Mac OS 10.6, Intel Macbook Pro
Edit2: GHCi 7.0.3 doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Can't reproduce. We need more details, e.g. GHC version and OS. Perhaps look for a fitting bug report.

Comment: 6.10.4 isn't that recent.  I'd recommend 7.0.3, or 6.12 if you need to stay with the ghc-6 line.

Comment: This is a bug that has come up here a few times before (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241728/haskell-negative-decimal-numbers , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101599/negative-doubles-or-floats-in-haskell-macports).  According to the latter, the problem is with the one MacPorts installs - the Haskell Platform from haskell.org works.  From personal experience, 6.10.* work fine on Mac OS 10.6 if installed from the haskell.org downloads as well.

Comment: Looks like dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101599/negative-doubles-or-floats-in-haskell-macports indeed.

Comment: @mokus: Good find; thank you! I think I did install with MacPorts last time.
@all: Why would the MacPorts version be any different than the haskell.org version? Especially with something so completely broken like segfaulting because of a negative float?

Comment: My guess (and it's nothing more than a guess) is that it has to do with the fact that GHC actually interacts in very, very intimate ways with GMP, including (if I understand correctly) making GMP use GHC's memory allocator.  MacPorts probably isn't particularly careful about respecting that delicate dependency, and any number of things could go wrong.  Perhaps it builds against one version of GMP, works for a while, but then the next time you `port upgrade outdated` it upgrades gmp without recompiling GHC, breaking GHC in the process?

Comment: (continued)  Or maybe MacPorts applies some patches to GMP that "fix" something for Mac OS, but then that patched GMP is subtly different from the ones GHC was tested with, in ways that break assumptions made by the GHC developers.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, I don't get a segfault here (on MacOS this is):

```
GHCi, version 7.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading package ffi-1.0 ... linking ... done.

Prelude> let f x = 1/((x**2)-36)  
Prelude> f (0 - 6.5)  
0.16
Prelude> f (0 - 5)  
-9.090909090909091e-2
Prelude>
```

Comment: Ok, so it's a bug. I had a fear my Haskell knowledge had some gaping hole.

Comment: @amindfv: I'm pretty sure that Haskell code should never segfault unless it's calling foreign functions, mucking with runtime internals, or using something like `unsafeCoerce`. So don't worry about your knowledge being wrong here!

Answer (score 1):

Works on windows XP with GHC 7.02:

```
GHCi, version 7.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading package ffi-1.0 ... linking ... done.
Prelude> let f x = 1/((x**2)-36)
Prelude> f (0 - 6.5)
0.16
Prelude> f (0 - 5.999)
-83.34027835650902
Prelude> f (0 - 5)
-9.090909090909091e-2
Prelude>
```

Answer (score 1):

> GHCi version 6.10.4, Mac OS 10.6, Intel Macbook Pro

First thing to do in a situation like this is to check against the most recent stable release of the software.

- GHC 6.10.4 was released in July 2009.
- GHC 7.0.3 is available now, in May 2011.

So upgrade to GHC 7.0.3, via the [Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/), and check again.

If you still have a bug, report it via [the bug tracker](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/newticket?type=bug) , since any crash requires a high priority bug fix.